# How to store timestamps? Are created and updated fields available automatically?

Tags: mongodb

What's the best way to store timestamps in MongoDB?

1. Which format is best:

   ```
   # "created": { "d" : "2010-03-29", "t" : "20:15:34" }
   # "created": "12343545234" # seconds since epoc
   # "created": "2010-03-14T21:20:14+0000"
   ```
2. Is there a way to have MongoDB automatically set `created` and `updated` fields?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Which format is best

Best for what?

> Is there a way to have MongoDB automatically set created and updated fields?

Created time is in the [ObjectId](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-TheBSONObjectIdDatatype) but, as far as I know, you will have to update a `updated` field manually.

Example:

```
ObjectId("538141a9615760fd04ffef5f").getTimestamp()
```

Comment: Not trusting the time on the server? How about adding a field to your document?

Comment: yup I figured out that later.

Answer (score 6):

1. The format you need to process it with best performance in your application should be preferred. Note that as default every document in MongoDB gets a created timestamp (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-DocumentTimestamps)
2. See 1) + I think you need to manually set the "update" field.

Comment: & @Jonas Thanks guys, I forgot about the timestamp in the _id. Anyone else know if there's an automatic way to store `updated`?

Answer (score 5):

If you do following on mongo shell it shows you time stamp that represents when that documents inserted using mongoId. For ex. `ObjectId("51f3dee5ee49f9b91e0db133").getTimestamp()`, then it returns `ISODate`.

Answer (score 3):

you need to pass an object as a second argument to your Schema and set the timestamp to true like this

`const newSchema = new Schema({ username: {type: String} }, {timestamps: true})`

mongodb provides the fields createdAt and UpdatedAt for you

Comment: Thanks, but I think this is a feature of Mongoose, not MongoDB.

Answer (score 2):

In 1.8 and above Mongo has a way to create 64-bit timestamp values which are guaranteed unique on a single server.  But they're not updated automatically.  http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Timestamp+data+type